# How can I easily create web 2.0 buttons?

Tags: graphics

Is there a website or software I can use to easily make web 2.0 buttons?  I really like this:  https://github.com/imathis/fancy-buttons, but it's only for Ruby.

Every time I design a new website, I need to go into Fireworks and tediously create the buttons by hand.  Surely someone out there must have come up with an easy way of making new web buttons.

Comment: I meant Fireworks, not Firefox.

Comment: Web 2.0 was 5 years ago, we're on Web 7.5 by now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://jirox.net/AsButtonGen/ It's an in-browser Flash application that lets you create Web 2.0 buttons and export them as PNG files.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what this has to do with web 2.0, but CSS buttons are fairly straightforward to make. (That's their advantage over image buttons.) Just design the style for a single button and apply to all buttons of that class. If you want to use the same style of buttons across multiple sites, just copy and paste the code and change the colors. Unless you have a hundred different button styles, it shouldn't take you more than a minute or two.

No script is going to be able to automatically determine what style or color of buttons best suits your layout. So you'll still need to pick the colors yourself. I'm not sure how a script will speed that up.

And why are you designing buttons in *Firefox* anyway? It's a lot easier to pick out colors (and button style) in a real graphics program while you're designing the layout and just copy and paste the color code into the stylesheet.

Comment: I'm assuming he'd be using Firebug to create the HTML & CSS live.

Comment: @Kevin: That's what I mean. When you just type in color codes in Firebug, you're basically guessing at the hue/shade it'll produce. It's quicker to just use the color picker in something like Photoshop where you can pick the precise colors you want and know exactly what the hex code will be.

Answer (score 0):

bestattendance - In addition to the Jirox.net site Kevin Mark suggested, try [Da Button Factory](http://dabuttonfactory.com/).  The interface is a little less finicky.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a good way to make nice buttons for a long time now. I just found something that looks pretty good: http://freebuttons.org/index.html

- Lets you **modify all** the **colors** (so we can match our website theme)
- Includes **Rollover effects**. It even sets the rollover color automatically. ( I took a dark red background button which had a light red "mouse over" effect color and changed it to blue. The program automatically changed the background color to light blue).
- **Inserts** the code right **into HTML** of the page.
- Uses CSS  (which is good and bad. I'm not sure how well it works in older browsers)
- Free version that's pretty powerful. Paid version has more themes for just $30

Answer (score 0):

Here's a site where you can download free web buttons. There are thousands of buttons available on this site. The site link is http://www.btnfinder.com/

Comment: It's ok to mention your own site, but you need to tell us your links with the site. Can you update your answer to tell us that? Are you the site owner? As you've put the name of the site in your profile I presume you are.